# Should I use generics to solve this issue?

Tags: java, design-patterns, generics, interface, return-type

At the moment I have an interface which looks like the following:

```
public interface IUserManagement {
    public void storeUser(UserDataObject u);
    public void removeUser(String userToRemove);
    public void verifyUser(UserDataObject u);
    public void banUserStatus(String userToBan);
    public void changeRole(String userToChange, String newRole);
    public void unBan(String unBanUser);
}
```

Its worked fine for 2 other classes that implement it, but now I have another class which I want to implement it - but with one tiny different. the method:

> storeUser(UserDataObject u)

needs to return a boolean this time!

This is the first time I have run into this problem, and I know there is way to solve this, but I'm just not quite sure how to do it. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Comment: You need to make a choice, a single class can't have a `boolean findUser()` and a `void(findUser)` at the same time. The compiler would not be able to tell which to call...

Comment: You can change the return-type for the other two classes to boolean too. If you call the method from one of the other classes simply ignor the return.

Comment: Ok! I thought there was a way round this, but I guess not. I'll just make my other methods return a boolean and ignore them! (doesn't sound like good programming practice though to return stuff that aren't used?)

Comment: Sometimes you just don't need the return of some functions. Its normal to just ignore them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions, you decide:
1. make another interface with `boolean` return type
2. change the return type to `boolean` (recommended as you can always return true if in fact info were stored)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! (and pad and assylias). I'm still new to OOP programming and I want to make sure I get into the habit of good programming practices early on so thanks.